# Starmap combined with tqdm?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, tqdm, process-pool

I am doing some parallel processing, as follows:

```
with mp.Pool(8) as tmpPool:
        results = tmpPool.starmap(my_function, inputs)
```

where inputs look like:
    [(1,0.2312),(5,0.52) ...]
i.e., tuples of an int and a float.

The code runs nicely, yet I cannot seem to wrap it around a loading bar (tqdm), such as can be done with e.g., imap method as follows:

```
tqdm.tqdm(mp.imap(some_function,some_inputs))
```

Can this be done for starmap also?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, I would say change your `my_function` to receive one packed argument and unpack it inside the function and then use `imap`

Comment: Yes, that is the default solution currently. I am still wondering whether starmap supports this (or any variant of it)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of or can see in the docs. The only variant I know of is `starmap_async` which is simply non-blocking but still returns a result object. I believe you will have to adjust your function to work with `imap` as it is the only option that works as a generator and not returning all results at once. Will be happy to see if there is a better solution

Comment: Thanks, Currently, I've re-implemented it with imap. Would be nice to have the istarmap also!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's not possible with `starmap()`, but it's possible with a patch adding `Pool.istarmap()`. It's based on the code for `imap()`. All you have to do, is create the `istarmap.py`-file and import the module to apply the patch before you make your regular multiprocessing-imports.

**Python <3.8**

```
# istarmap.py for Python <3.8
import multiprocessing.pool as mpp


def istarmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
    """starmap-version of imap
    """
    if self._state != mpp.RUN:
        raise ValueError("Pool not running")

    if chunksize < 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Chunksize must be 1+, not {0:n}".format(
                chunksize))

    task_batches = mpp.Pool._get_tasks(func, iterable, chunksize)
    result = mpp.IMapIterator(self._cache)
    self._taskqueue.put(
        (
            self._guarded_task_generation(result._job,
                                          mpp.starmapstar,
                                          task_batches),
            result._set_length
        ))
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)


mpp.Pool.istarmap = istarmap
```

**Python 3.8+**

```
# istarmap.py for Python 3.8+
import multiprocessing.pool as mpp


def istarmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
    """starmap-version of imap
    """
    self._check_running()
    if chunksize < 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Chunksize must be 1+, not {0:n}".format(
                chunksize))

    task_batches = mpp.Pool._get_tasks(func, iterable, chunksize)
    result = mpp.IMapIterator(self)
    self._taskqueue.put(
        (
            self._guarded_task_generation(result._job,
                                          mpp.starmapstar,
                                          task_batches),
            result._set_length
        ))
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)


mpp.Pool.istarmap = istarmap
```

Then in your script:

```
import istarmap  # import to apply patch
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm    


def foo(a, b):
    for _ in range(int(50e6)):
        pass
    return a, b    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(4) as pool:
        iterable = [(i, 'x') for i in range(10)]
        for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.istarmap(foo, iterable),
                           total=len(iterable)):
            pass
```

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what I was after! Thanks!

Comment: I get `AttributeError: '_PoolCache' object has no attribute '_cache'` - any ideas? It occurs at the line `result = mp.IMapIterator(self._cache)`

Comment: @wfgeo I'm using `mpp` as name for the module, your example uses `mp`. Do you get the error with exactly my example from the answer, too?

Comment: Yes I just replaced `mpp` and `mp`, it's just a personal convention, sorry. I do get the error with the same code, but it was because I had not called the module `istarmap`. I am currently having trouble bundling it into my own module, however, I can't seem to figure out the import statement if I put istarmap as a submodule in my own module

Comment: @wfgeo That's okay, I just didn't knew if you had some other module named `mp`. I'm afraid that's not really enough information to understand your problem, but you need to import  `istarmap` _before_ you import anything else from multiprocessing.

Comment: @wfgeo I get the same error you did. 
For me it had not anything t do with the abbreviation `mpp` vs `mp` but i had to alter the following line. 
Instead of 
`result = mpp.IMapIterator(self._cache)` i need `result = mpp.IMapIterator(self)`

By inspecting it in the debugger is, that the constructor of `IMapIterator` needs to get a Pool instance, and not the cache (c.f. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L838)

Comment: @physicus Thanks, I looked into it and saw they did some breaking changes in Python 3.8. There's a bit more to tweak, than just replacing `self._cache`, I've updated my answer with a version for Python 3.8.

Comment: @Darkonaut With your code how do you retrieve the outputs of the function? With starmap for example we just used result = pool.starmap(....)

Comment: @JulienDrevon It's already iterating over the results. In the example the results is assigned to `_`, within `for _ in tqdm.tqdm(...`, because the result doesn't get used, but that's just convention for this case. You could write `for result in tqdm.tqdm(...` and then `print(result)` on every iteration or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 52):

The simplest way would probably be to apply tqdm() around the inputs, rather than the mapping function. For example:

```
inputs = zip(param1, param2, param3)
with mp.Pool(8) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(my_function, tqdm.tqdm(inputs, total=len(param1)))
```

Note that the bar is updated when `my_function` is called, rather than when it returns. If that distinction matters, you can consider rewriting starmap as some other answers suggest. Otherwise, this is a simple and efficient alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should be the accepted answer, I think. I had to pass the input length as `total` to `tqdm` to make it work.

Comment: You're correct, you'll likely need the total arg for streaming/lazy iterables

Comment: Quick update: this did provide the progress bar, but the updates were not as dynamic as I hoped. It froze too much.

Comment: Did you use chunksize != 1? It's possible elements were being pulled from the input in chunks so the progress bar updated irregularly

Comment: Thanks, having `chunksize != 1` helped and made it a smoother bar!

Comment: res_1, res_2 = zip(*pool.starmap(order2seq_multiproc, tqdm(tasks, total=len(tasks)))). This my code but the progress bar is always full and no update. Where should add the chunksize != 1? I put it right after total, it doesn't work, saying "name 'chunksize' is not defined"

Comment: chunksize is a parameter of starmap, not tqdm. So try pool.starmap(order2seq_multiproc, tqdm(input), chunksize=chunksize)

Comment: Note: a zip object doesn't have a length. Instead, total=len(param1) would work

Comment: This seems to only track when the inputs are being sent, but not when the processing of `my_function` is completed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware but gofvonx is right. This measures input- not output-progression. That's also why this appears to be faster as some people commented. Now imagine all but the last task taking up five seconds but the last one hour to complete. You could end up with getting displayed 100% progress for almost an hour before the actual finish...

Comment: Progresbar progresses very quickly and get to the %100, and then it still continues to run until it is done.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work anymore because the implementation of starmap creates the tasks straightaway.

Answer (score 20):

As Darkonaut mentioned, as of this writing there's no `istarmap` natively available. If you want to avoid patching, you can add a simple *`_star` function as a workaround. (This solution inspired by [this tutorial.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples))

```py
import tqdm
import multiprocessing

def my_function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
  return arg1 + arg2 + arg3

def my_function_star(args):
    return my_function(*args)

jobs = 4
with multiprocessing.Pool(jobs) as pool:
    args = [(i, i, i) for i in range(10000)]
    results = list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap(my_function_star, args), total=len(args))
```

---

Some notes:

I also really like corey's answer. It's cleaner, though the progress bar does not appear to update as smoothly as my answer. Note that corey's answer is several orders of magnitude faster with the code I posted above with `chunksize=1` (default). I'm guessing this is due to multiprocessing serialization, because increasing `chunksize` (or having a more expensive `my_function`) makes their runtime comparable.

I went with my answer for my application since my serialization/function cost ratio was very low.

Comment: This is the best answer! Your notes about corey's answer is on point!

Comment: This is great, thanks! I think as an extension to this, you can write a general function `f_star(f, args)` that returns `f(*args)`. Then you can write this as a utility function and use it anywhere you want to use `tqdm` with `starmap`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my suggestion, it should say `f_star(f_args)` takes a tuple of `(f, args)` and returns `f(*args)`.

Answer (score -4):

The temporary solution: rewriting the method to-be-parallelized with imap.